# How to properly fix CSS inconsistencies across desktop and mobile browsers?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm designing [this login form](http://archify.com/user/login) using the [GGS responsive grid](http://goldengridsystem.com/) (CSS) and although it looks cool on desktop browsers, it miserably breaks in mobile browsers (e.g. Android web browser, Mobile Safari, etc). How should I properly fix this inconsistency?

[image: Layout breaks in Mobile Safari (left), but not in desktop browsers like Chrome (right)]
<sub>**Above**: layout breaks in Mobile Safari (left), but not in desktop browsers like Chrome (right).</sub>

Comment: This has none. Do you mean in my other questions?

Comment: Yes I did. It says you just accepted 3 out of 11 possible answers, which seems quiet low.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Sirko. It's still weird, though: I can't see any answers for this question..

Comment: Sry, I can't help you here, as I have no way of testing at the moment. When looking at your code, however, I find some typos you should correct in the CSS: `fontsize` instead of `font-size` or `:visiyet` instead of `:visited`. Maybe you should check those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing the `width` parameter from the buttons, as it somehow seems to be interpreted differently across both mobile and desktop browsers in mobile resolutions.